# Как узнать telegram ID автора пересланого сообщения?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Пишу телеграм-бот, и решил добавить функцию, которая выдаёт ID автора пересланого сообщения. И у меня сразу две проблемы: во-первых, как получить ID человека, который написал пересланое сообщение? Во-вторых, как взять этот ID из сообщения ниже?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['id'])
def id(msg):
message = msg.from_user.id
```

возьмёт id пользователя, который написал /id как и сообщение, соответсвенно. 1)Как взять ID сообщения ниже? 2)Сработает ли при этом `message_under.from_user.id`, что бы получить ID именно автора, а не человека, который переслал сообщение?

Comment: извините, а можете дать id своего бота?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понятно какая библиотека используется, но согласно документации Telegram Bot API, у обьекта message должен быть аттрибут `forward_from` типа User.

Ответ: `message.forward_from.user`

Comment: Ой, извините. Использую telebot, так что ответ подходит. Спасибо!

Comment: Кстати, милый котик на аватарке =)

Answer (score 0):

Если человек в настройках приватности телеграма запретил, то уже никак и Ваш код выдаст None